# Exception when using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext function

Tags: java, spring, ioexception

I was using the **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** to read my xml. But on execution I am getting the error as stated under . I have also  checked the file names and I  have also executed the same program using **XmlBeanFactory** function which returns the desired output

Here  is my code

```
  package org.lalit.springsession;

  import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
  import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
  import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

  public class DrawingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



         /*
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new        FileSystemResource("spring.xml")) ;
    Triangle triangle=  (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
    */

    BeanFactory factoryObj = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle=  (Triangle) factoryObj.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
}
```

}

These are Exceptions which I am facing.

```
   May 06, 2014 1:53:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@14a1ee92: startup date [Tue May 06 13:53:42 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    May 06, 2014 1:53:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [C:/Users/Lalit/workspace/DemoSpring/spring.xml]
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [C:/Users/Lalit/workspace/DemoSpring/spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/Users/Lalit/workspace/DemoSpring/spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at org.lalit.springsession.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:24)
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/Users/Lalit/workspace/DemoSpring/spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Check if that file exists in that location C:/Users/Lalit/workspace/DemoSpring/spring.xml. Error says it does not exists.

Comment: Downvote from me as the code provided can not generate the mentioned exception. Please fix it if you want to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `spring.xml` isn't on your classpath, it resides somewhere on your file system. Your `XmlBeanFactory` is loading the file from the file system the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` defaults to the classpath.

Either move the file to your classpath or modify the constructing of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and prefix with `file:`.

```
    BeanFactory factoryObj = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:spring.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct.The problem here is the spring file is not loaded by the Drawing class So add your spring.xml file to the classpath by moving spring.xml to the src folder of your project..